# Send response as code snippet for slack slash command

Tags: javascript, slack-commands

I am creating a slack slash command and I want to return a javascript object (a JSON response from another api call) as code.

---EDIT---

I can send a markdown response using the code below. The issue now is that I cannot show JSON / JavaScript object as formatted code. the `data` argument is an API response of JSON and I wanted to show that as code.

I have tried sending it as plain `data` as JSON.stringify(data), but nothing seems to work.

---Second EDIT---

Have it working now with the following implementation. The accepted answer below prompted me to try the following (in case anyone comes looking for this)

```js
createResponse = function (data) {
  const date = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

  return {
      "response_type": "ephemeral", // only show message to user who issued command
      "attachments": [
        {
          "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
          "fallback": data,
          "color": "#002868",
          "pretext": 'Here you go...',
          "text": `\`\`\`${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}\`\`\``,
          "footer": "Here you go...",
          "ts": date,
        }
      ]
  };
};
```

Comment: What is the problem you get when you use `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: it displays as `[object Object]`

Comment: Before the `return`, add `console.log(typeof data);`. Run the command and check the console logs. If it says "string", it means this function is receiving `data` as a string and something else is mangling the data before this function is called.

Comment: (`[object Object]` usually comes from something like `someObject.toString()`. So I suspect that the data has had `.toString()` used on it and the results of that are being passed to this function. If that's the case, `typeof data`, in the test I suggested, would return `string`.)

Comment: Please include an example of `data` and the API. as it applies to `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a a bit of a wild shot have try to add ```` ``` ````  for format your return string

````js
const returnValue =  {
      "response_type": "ephemeral", // only show message to user who issued command
      "attachments": [
        {
          "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
          "fallback": data,
          "color": "#002868",
          "pretext": 'Here you go...',
          "text":"```" + JSON.stringify(someObject)  
          "footer": "Here you go...",
          "ts": date,
        }
      ]
  };
````

https://slack.com/intl/it-it/help/articles/202288908-Formattare-i-messaggi

Comment: Not so wild it turns out. However I think the missing link for me was actually formatting with JSON.stringify. this is my working solution "text": `\`\`\`${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}\`\`\``,